# Share an enum among classes

Tags: c#, class, enums, namespaces

I have 2 classes in different files in the same namespace.
I need to share an `enum` between them. I tried to define it in one of them as `internal` - didn't work for me (the other class does not recognize the `enum`)
What could be a solution?

Comment: can you show as the code u used please,,,? we dont even know what caused your problem....

Comment: Is the enum public?  Is it nested inside a class that's not public?

Comment: not public,nested in static public class

Answer (score 1):

File 1:

```
namespace GlobalNameSpace 
{
    public class FirstClass
    {

    }
}
```

File 2:

```
namespace GlobalNameSpace 
{
    public class SecondClass
    {

    }
}
```

File 3:

```
namespace GlobalNameSpace 
{
    public enum SharedEnum
    {
         FirstValue,
         SecondValue,
         ThirdValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your enum in another class and put your enum in there. Then reference that class in both your other classes